# How can I take advantage of repeated patterns in non random RSA prime factors?

Tags: rsa, public-key, random-number-generator, factoring

I am researching vulnerable RSA moduli which are composed of primes generated with poor entropy. Having a list of these primes I searched for variable sized repeated patterns among them and I noticed the following:

`DD93536E58A60B0F56BF95FAEDC7CA42A9C9809A`0AAE2FC971C3D9963587ABCEAF2BAB479A68DDC9EFF0E98F0F5FD488A9DD08CC51C01E9A3CFE46CA10BF6AB5
`DD93536E58A60B0F56BF95FAEDC7CA42A9C9809A`2CF5B9957C2E6FD04E817F03D2E174BB79364A0FC0BF365807A1F9E3286A04EB90FBE9DD52B0A2F12222AB51
`DD93536E58A60B0F56BF95FAEDC7CA42A9C9809A`BB02D6D274A02869AF059E586EED6DC634FCC33C455504DD40FC43D23544AC4E8F2C5E5C64E3E7530C7EDB07
`DD93536E58A60B0F56BF95FAEDC7CA42A9C9809A`CEF6287DF02847947530B8CA9A125ACCB53EC922D6E9775A3B0169894ED5A46B281C17AF4583874B715B07BB

Four distinct primes have in common their first 160 bits. Apart from being obvious that these primes have been generated by a weak random number generator how can they be used to derive some other primes generated from the same RNG that are potential factors of other moduli?

Comment: What is this question in mathematician's speech?

Comment: @Hans Stricker: knowing integer $n$, that $n=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ unknown primes in range$[2^{1023/2}\dots2^{1024/2}]$, and the integer $\bar p=\lfloor p/2^{512-160}\rfloor$, find $p$. _Perhaps_ it is possible to assume that $\lfloor p/2^{512-320}\rfloor$ falls into a relatively short list of known possible values; that could help tremendously.

Comment: If the answers to [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8258/555) are correct, _asymptotically_, one cannot efficiently factor an RSA modulus $N$ from knowledge of less than $1/4\cdot\log_2(N)$ of extra bits. Sounds like rather bad news for the problem in the question, where the proportion of known bits is $160/1024=5/32\ll1/4$; we need some more bits, or lots of effort.

Comment: @fgrieu the primes that I present here are non random but **valid** factors of some existing RSA moduli. The objective is, given those factors, look for repeated patterns and try generate somehow some **new** factors that can factorise some other moduli. Presumably these factors are generated from a poorly seeded PRNG

Comment: @hask: My understanding/assumption is that the only known pattern occurs for the 160 first bits of one prime (likely, the first generated) in a given modulus, and you have nothing exploitable about the remaining bits in the primes. That would be consistent with a RNG based on SHA-1, poorly seeded, and that you have not analyzed beyond that observation. My former remark shows that you need a better analysis of the RNG, or progress towards improving the bound in the answers to the linked question, or a lot of computational power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 1 of ["Implicit Factoring with Shared Most Significant and Middle_Bits"](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221010790_Implicit_Factoring_with_Shared_Most_Significant_and_Middle_Bits?ev=pub_cit_inc) by Jean-Charles Faugère, Raphaël Marinier, Guénaël Renault from 2010 deals with factoring products of two primes where some fraction of the MSBs are common to one of the primes in each of the composites. If I read their bounds correctly, their method must only be useful for quite unbalanced primes.

"Let $N_1=p_1*q_1,N_2=p_2*q_2$ be two n-bit RSA moduli, where the $q_i$s are $\alpha$-bit primes and the $p_i$s are primes that share the $t$-most significant bits, If $t>2*\alpha+3$ then $N_1$ and $N_2$ can be factored in time quadratic in $n$"

Comment: Similar work has been done also by _May_ and _Maitre_. It should be highlighted, as you correctly said, that the two composites of the moduli have to be **unbalanced**.

Comment: In the question, I guess the moduli are 1024-bit and balanced; and we have examples of output of the badly seeded RNG, thus it is not far fetched to say that we know (with non-negligible probability) the top 160 bits in _one_ of the factors of the public modulus to be factorized, something not considered in the paper referenced. Problem is, there are not enough known bits (160 out of 1024; there is no reason to believe that both primes in a modulus are generated from poor seed) for any known attack, and a better analysis of the RNG seems necessary.