# Factoring a semiprime with part of one of its factors

Tags: passwords, factoring

This is part of a question I asked on [information security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133544/simple-to-implement-ad-hoc-password-validation-scheme?noredirect=1) which might be better suited here.

I'm looking to implement a script in an ad-hoc scripting language with no crypto libraries, which can tell whether or not a password is valid without revealing the password.  I also need the password to be as short as possible without being crackable.

One possibility is to store a large semiprime and have the password be a factor.  But semiprimes need to have factors which are hundreds of bits long to be difficult to crack. I'd rather the password be around 64 bits.  I'm considering storing a 1024-bit semiprime along with 448 bits of one of its 512-bit factors, and have the other 64 bits be the password, but I have no idea if this is crackable.

So my question is:  If a 1024-bit semiprime is stored along with the first 448 bits of one of its 512-bit factors, can the remaining 64 bits of that factor be feasibly found?

Comment: Are you assuming that the attacker (or your friend, in this case) will reverse engineer the application, but not modify it?

Comment: Can your language call external libraries?

Comment: FWIW, posting the same question on multiple SE sites is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @EllaRose No, it's sandboxed.  Basically, it allows you to write a custom level without doing anything that would break the game.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, they will reverse engineer it but not modify it.
Do you think I should remove the question from here or from information security?  I wasn't aware of this SE site when I posted it there.

Comment: Personally I think the bit about whether or not leaking 448 bits of a 512-bit factor of a [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) would be a pretty good question on here. The question about "is there another way" might be better left on Security.SE.

Comment: I was looking for it, and finally found it, I think your first question about factoring a semiprime given some bits of one of the factors has [already been explored here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/rsa-leak-bits-to-factor-n). Though what is not clear to me is how those answer apply since you don't have an $e$.

Comment: @mikeazo Thanks.  That answers my question.  I guess I'll just implement some standard hashing algorithm then.

Comment: @cardboard_box, I'm posting a different option on Security.SE for you.

Comment: Just to clear things up, I'll close this as a duplicate of the other, then update my answer on the other. The results of the Coppersmith theorem still apply. The size of $e$ only matters when given bits of $d$.